# Nil is not compatible with expected argument type CGAffineTransform

Tags: swift, swift3, cgaffinetransform, cgrect, cgpath

I am trying to draw a path : `CGMutablePath` but I am facing problem while adding path.  Nil is not compatible with expected argument type `'UnsafePointer'CGAffineTransform'`

[image]

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

            let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

            let path = CGMutablePath()
            CGPathAddArc(path, nil, centerX, centerY, radius, -CGFloat(M_PI/2), CGFloat(GLKMathDegreesToRadians(currentAngle)), false)

            context!.addPath(path)
            context!.setStrokeColor(UIColor.blue.cgColor)
            context!.setLineWidth(3)
            context!.strokePath()
       }
```

Tried few things replace nil with `0, options: nil, options: [ ]` none of these worked.

With the help of @vadian answer.
Solution:

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

            let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!

            let path = CGMutablePath()
            path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x:centerX, y:centerY), radius: radius, startAngle: -(CGFloat.pi / 2), endAngle: CGFloat(GLKMathDegreesToRadians(currentAngle)), clockwise: false)

            context.addPath(path)
            context.setStrokeColor(UIColor.blue.cgColor)
            context.setLineWidth(3)
            context.strokePath()
       }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The signature of the function of `CGMutablePath` to add an arc in Swift 3 is

```
func addArc(center: CGPoint, radius: CGFloat, startAngle: CGFloat, endAngle: CGFloat, clockwise: Bool, transform: CGAffineTransform = default)
```

in your case (`center` must be a `CGPoint`)

```
path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x:centerX, y:centerY), 
            radius: radius, 
        startAngle: -(CGFloat.pi / 2), 
          endAngle: CGFloat(GLKMathDegreesToRadians(currentAngle)), 
         clockwise: false)
```

To avoid the four exclamation marks unwrap the context directly

```
let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
```

and delete all other `!`.

Comment: Might also be nice to add a little example of how to avoid using all of the `!` in the OP's code.

Comment: @rmaddy The forced unwrapped context is perfectly fine in this particular case. According to the documentation any `UIView` provides a valid context before calling `drawRect` (*Prior to calling its drawRect: method, view objects push a valid context onto the stack, making it current.*)

Comment: Then do `let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!` and avoid the need for all of the `context!` uses.